# Using your calculator to find smallest solution ((natural) exponential function=log function)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am in need of some help with a problem that involves a (natural) exponential function ($e^x$) and a log function ($log$). So the question follows:

> Use your calculator to find the smallest solution to $-5e^{-4x+2}+3=\frac12log(x^2+1)$. Describe the steps you used. Round your answer to three decimals.

There are some things to note. I am working on a **TI-84 Plus** calculator. This is for a **High school Honors Pre-calculus Class** so it is **Algebra Based**. I just needed to tell you this as I have asked a question before and got a hardcore Calculus answer that looked like an alien language (but once in college, hopefully, it won't!) Also, thank you in advance! I really want to know how to do this.

Comment: It is a graphing calculator?  Can you use that to get approximate roots?  MathJax hint:  if you put backslashes before common functions you get the proper font and spacing, so \log x gives $\log x$ instead of log x which gives $log x$

Comment: Which base does the logarithm use? I believe that in the TI-84 a simple $\log()$ means base $10$--it certainly does in the TI-Nspire CX. Also, can't you just graph the two sides of the equation and find where the two graphs intersect? This is much faster and easier than using the bisection method or Newton's rule (as in the current answers), and nothing in your question prohibits the graphing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are expected to find a numeric approximation to the smallest positive root of $-5e^{-4x+2}+3-\frac12\log(x^2+1)=0$  The first challenge is finding a starting point.  This is a continuous function and you might notice that it is negative at $x=0$ and positive at $x=1$ so there is a root in the interval $(0,1)$.  That is why I asked if it was a graphing calculator.  I asked [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3-5e%5E(-4x%2B2)%3Dlog(x%5E2%2B1)%2F2) to graph it for me.  The simplest root finding approach is [bisection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method).   Once you have an interval over which the sign changes, evaluate the function at the center of the interval, then replace the endpoint where the function has the same sign with the center point.  That will cut the length of the interval in half each step.  You need about ten divisions in half to get three decimals, which is not so many.  There are other root finders that converge more quickly, but this is an easy one to describe.

Comment: Thank you very much! And to answer your question, yes. Log()  means base of 10 on the TI-84. Again, thank you!!

Comment: The fact that it is base 10 log doesn't change the approach and doesn't even move the root much.  Here is the [Alpha result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3-5e%5E(-4x%2B2)%3Dlog(10,x%5E2%2B1)%2F2) using log to base 10

Answer (score 0):

Consider that you look for the zero of function

$$f(x)=-5 e^{2-4 x}+3-\frac{1}{2} \log \left(x^2+1\right)$$ (I assumed it is $\log_e(.)$).

Use inspection (or plotting) to notice that

$$f(0)=3-5 e^2 \approx -33.9453 \qquad \text{and} \qquad f(1)=3-\frac{5}{e^2}-\frac{\log (2)}{2}\approx 1.97675$$ So, at least we know that there is root in $(0,1)$.

Let us use Newton method which, starting from a guess $x_0$, will update it according to 
$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)} {f'(x_n) }$$ In your case
$$f'(x)=20\, e^{2-4 x}-\frac{x}{x^2+1}$$ Both $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ are easy to program.

Start using $x_0=\frac 12$ (midpoint of the interaval) and proceed to get the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.5000000000 \\
 1 & 0.6077332539 \\
 2 & 0.6401268305 \\
 3 & 0.6425261884 \\
 4 & 0.6425383402 \\
 5 & 0.6425383405
\end{array}
\right)$$ which is the solution for ten significant figures.

Comment: You assume that the $\log()$ function is base $e$, rather than base $10$. Why is that?

Comment: @RoryDaulton. I thought it was $\log_e$. In fact, I must confess that I only know one logarithm !! I shall precise it. Cheers